# Jackson library 1.x array if one element sometimes just a string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have to deal with strange Json messages.

there are Arrays in the schema, but if there are only one element array becomes an string.

So sometimes it is:

```
        "Cisco-AVPair": [
            "connect-progress=Call Up", 
            "nas-tx-speed=8083000", 
            "nas-rx-speed=8083000"
        ],
```

and sometimes:

```
         "Cisco-AVPair": "connect-progress=Call Up".
```

How to overcome this if I use  Jackson 1.8.2

I am afraid I am not in control of source code generation and only can parse it.

I do parse it with:

```
         mapper.readValue(json, refType);
```

while my type reference is:

```
         @JsonProperty("Cisco-AVPair")
         private List<String> CiscoAVPair = new ArrayList<String>();

         @JsonProperty("Cisco-AVPair")
         public List<String> getCiscoAVPair() {
         return CiscoAVPair;
         }

         @JsonProperty("Cisco-AVPair")
         public void setCiscoAVPair(List<String> CiscoAVPair) {
         this.CiscoAVPair = CiscoAVPair;
         }
```

As you see it is list of strings, but sometimes comes just as a string.

Comment: Are you in control of the JSON generation?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify what the problem is, include the _related_ piece of code, some of the input data, and the expected output, so  we can help you.

Comment: I am not in control of generation, I would be happy to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a specific config option even in ancient Jackson 1.8.2 that accomplishes exactly what you need.

You should configure your `ObjectMapper` instance to always deserialize JSON values as a `List`, no matter whether values come as an array or as a single element. Please see [javadocs here](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-lgpl/1.8.2/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig.Feature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) for the deserialization feature you need to enable, and [these other javadocs](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-lgpl/1.8.2/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature,%20boolean)) to see how to actually activate/deactivate a feature on an `ObjectMapper` instance.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ...;
mapper = mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

Bear in mind that `configure()` method returns another instance of `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Is there any way to use in as an annotation?

Comment: @AtyabalVZopu I don't think so. But as you're actually using `mapper.readValue(json, refType);` to parse the JSON, I thought you had a reference to the underlying `ObjectMapper`. If this is the case, I don't see why you couldn't configure it with the option you need to always receive a `List`.